# None argument is considered as an argument

Tags: python

I am passing a None argument, and I was expecting my default parameter to be triggered as the parameter is **None** but it is not going as expected

```
def copy_and_rename(self,variable="X"):
    print(variable) # None instead of "X"
    return 0
```

I was finding this idea quite minimalist and enjoyable. How would you do ?

Comment: How are you calling this method? Should be called as `self.copy_and_rename()` if called inside the class or `my_object.copy_and_rename()` if called in another scope on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` is a valid argument. There is no value that will be ignored when passed and treated as a lack of an argument. If you want the behaviour you're after, you'd need to explicitly do a check for `None`:

```
def copy_and_rename(self,variable="X"):
    if variable is None:
        variable = "X"
    print(variable)
```

I don't think I'd recommend this though. I think it would be better to handle this at the call-site instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'll handle that at call-site :)

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat common to need to distinguish between a user calling a function with an argument set explicitly to `None` and a user not including an argument at all. (E.g. when `None` is a valid value.) The simplest and easiest way I've seen to do this is using a "dummy object" as the default like so:

```py
UNSET = object()

class Foo:

    def bar(self, argument=UNSET):
        if argument is UNSET:
            print('taking the default action')
        else:
            print(f'taking action for {argument = }')

> Foo().bar()
taking the default action

> Foo().bar(None)
taking action for argument = None

> Foo().bar(15)
taking action for argument = 15
```